# Accidentally deleted lib and lib64 from / on RHEL

Tags: linux, rhel, links

Could someone please guide how to give life back to the RHEL host where I accidentally deleted lib* from /

Now I can't run any command - I need to create links again as below:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 9 Aug 12  2018 lib64 -> usr/lib64
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 7 Aug 12  2018 lib -> usr/lib
```

How can I do this - I still have access to system and haven't rebooted as I know it will be gone once rebooted.

```
[root@srv01 lib64]# ls
-bash: /bin/ls: No such file or directory
[root@srv01 lib64]# mv
-bash: /bin/mv: No such file or directory
[root@srv01 lib64]# pwd
/usr/lib64
[root@srv01 lib64]# cd /usr/lib
[root@srv01 lib]# pwd
/usr/lib
[root@srv01 lib]#
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you learnt why backups are not a total waste of time. OK ! That won't help you now. Do you get access to any other system (same arch same processor family same version of libs) running elsewhere ?

Comment: Yes I do have same system available but can't ssh remotely as it doesn't find /bin/bash

Comment: Could you transfer files using (s)ftp ?

Comment: that host giving me connection closed when trying with sftp

Comment: `/usr/bin/commandname`

Comment: If all you did was delete `/lib` and `/lib64` then the problem isn't too bad. Boot from a live usb, mount the system's disks, and recreate the links. `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib64` are still there.

Comment: thanks doneal - thats what we did and system came back to life.